# How to modify struct passed by reference?

Tags: c++, struct, undefined

I'm passing a struct to a function by reference since I want to modify the struct inside the function. However, the compiler keeps giving me "Error C1421: Undefined class/struct/union" at "++kpad.pin_chars;". What am I missing? Here's my test code:

```
struct Keypad{
   int pin_chars;
};


void check_keypad(struct Keypad *kpad);


void main(void){
    struct Keypad kpad; 
    kpad.pin_chars = 0;
    check_keypad(&kpad);
}


void check_keypad(struct Keypad *kpad){
    ++kpad.pin_chars;
}
```

Comment: In the function check_keypad, kpad is a pointer to a structure and not the structure itself

Comment: Neither does C support classes nor references. The error message is not from a C compiler, but from C++. This is a different language, don't spam tags! While C++ supports references, there is none in your code; a pointer is not a reference!

Comment: Where from ym comment do you read I don't understand the question? Please take the [tour] to see what comments and answers are for. Maybe you noticed the postings below are headed "Answers", not comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a pointer, using the `struct Keypad *kpad` syntax. That's the `*` part.

When you are passing a pointer, you cannot use "dot" to access a member without first *dereferencing* the pointer. You must dereference or use "arrow" (`->`) as your operator:

```
++ *kpad.pin_chars
```

or

```
++kpad->pin_chars
```

In general, when using pointers the arrow syntax is the preferred approach.

**Edit:**

It's worth pointing out the [*precedence*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence) of the various operators involved. Postfix `++` (and `--`) have the same precedence as `.` and `->`, but would bind to the member in `ptr->member++` due to location, whereas prefix `++` (and `--`) have a lower precedence than `.` and `->`, and so bind to the result of the member-access expression as a result of precedence, not position.

You get the result in two slightly different ways.

Comment: You don't *have* to use the arrow operator. It's just a bit of syntactic sugar for the more verbose `(*kpad).pin_chars`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I spent hours on this.

Answer (score 1):

Since you passed a parameter by address, you need to de-reference it to get to its value. The following code works:

```
void check_keypad(struct Keypad *kpad){
 ++((*kpad).pin_chars);
}
```

C provides another format for the same purpose:

```
void check_keypad(struct Keypad *kpad){
 ++(kpad->pin_chars);
}
```